# Change Windows Firewall Settings With PowerShell But Do Not Show Output

Tags: sql, powershell, firewall

I have a PowerShell script I am using to install SQL Express, then SQL Server Management Studio, and finally, to edit the Windows Firewall settings to allow remote connections to the database.  For the firewall changes, one of the lines I'm running is:

```
New-NetFirewallRule -DisplayName "MSSQL ENGINE TCP" -Direction Inbound -LocalPort 1433 -Protocol TCP -Action Allow

Write-Host 'Windows Firewall configured to allow incoming connections on TCP port 1433'
```

Ideally, I would like the output to simply be:

```
Windows Firewall configured to allow incoming connections on TCP port 1433
```

Instead, I'm getting:

```
Caption                 :
Description             :
ElementName             : MSSQL ENGINE TCP
InstanceID              : {752a3c18-298f-4639-a462-4cc5205b1016}
CommonName              :
PolicyKeywords          :
Enabled                 : True
PolicyDecisionStrategy  : 2
PolicyRoles             :
ConditionListType       : 3
CreationClassName       : MSFT|FW|FirewallRule|{752a3c18-298f-4639-a462- 
4cc5205b1016}
ExecutionStrategy       : 2
Mandatory               :
PolicyRuleName          :
Priority                :
RuleUsage               :
SequencedActions        : 3
SystemCreationClassName :
SystemName              :
Action                  : Allow
Direction               : Inbound
DisplayGroup            :
DisplayName             : MSSQL ENGINE TCP
EdgeTraversalPolicy     : Block
EnforcementStatus       : NotApplicable
LocalOnlyMapping        : False
LooseSourceMapping      : False
Owner                   :
Platforms               : {}
PolicyStoreSource       : PersistentStore
PolicyStoreSourceType   : Local
PrimaryStatus           : OK
Profiles                : 0
RuleGroup               :
Status                  : The rule was parsed successfully from the store. (65536)
StatusCode              : 65536
PSComputerName          :
Name                    : {752a3c18-298f-4639-a462-4cc5205b1016}
ID                      : {752a3c18-298f-4639-a462-4cc5205b1016}
Group                   :
Platform                : {}
LSM                     : False
Profile                 : Any

Windows Firewall configured to allow incoming connections on TCP port 1433
```

Is there an easy way to eliminate all the excess from showing up in the PowerShell window?  I know I could create a second script and prompt that to run in a separate window, but I'm trying to accomplish this with a single script.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following will suppress command output and still execute the command:

```
$null = New-NetFirewallRule -DisplayName "MSSQL ENGINE TCP" -Direction Inbound -LocalPort 1433 -Protocol TCP -Action Allow
Write-Host 'Windows Firewall configured to allow incoming connections on TCP port 1433'
```

When an output is saved to `$null`, the output is removed.

You can also cast to `[void]`, which in certain cases may yield better performance than assigning to `$null`.

```
[void](New-NetFirewallRule -DisplayName "MSSQL ENGINE TCP" -Direction Inbound -LocalPort 1433 -Protocol TCP -Action Allow)
```

It is probably going to be negligible performance-wise with either case. You should **avoid using `Out-Null`** in all cases because that will always be slower.

It is generally not recommended to use `Write-Host`, but since I don't know how you are calling or executing your code, I am leaving that there. If you are executing this within the PowerShell console, you can simply just leave the quoted text on a line by itself.

Here are some performance tests to compare the three methods:

**Out-Null:**

```
$list = @() -as [system.collections.arraylist]
measure-command {(1..10000) | Foreach-Object {$list.add($_) | Out-Null} } | Select-Object -Property ticks,totalmilliseconds

  Ticks TotalMilliseconds
  ----- -----------------
6354765          635.4765
```

**[void]:**

```
$list = @() -as [system.collections.arraylist]
measure-command {(1..10000) | Foreach-Object {[void]$list.add($_)} } | Select-Object -Property ticks,totalmilliseconds

  Ticks TotalMilliseconds
  ----- -----------------
1323269          132.3269
```

**$null:**

```
$list = @() -as [system.collections.arraylist]
measure-command {(1..10000) | Foreach-Object {$null = $list.add($_)} } | Select-Object -Property  ticks,totalmilliseconds

  Ticks TotalMilliseconds
  ----- -----------------
1269874          126.9874
```

Comment: please, would you go back and expand your alias/shorthand stuff? ///// when doing demo code, i would strongly recommend you use the full cmdlet names & parameter names. you used both `%` and `select`, plus you didn't use `-Property` with the `Select-Object` cmdlet. it's worth while to be fairly explicit - both for those who are learning AND for the usual "readable = understandable = maintainable" idea. [*grin*] i confess that i am too lazy to use the `-Process` parameter name with the `ForEach-Object` call ... [*blush*]

Answer (score 1):

Run the cmdlet. Pipeout to `Out-Null`. If prior command succeeded, display message.

```
New-NetFirewallRule -DisplayName "MSSQL ENGINE TCP" -Direction Inbound -LocalPort 1433 -Protocol TCP -Action Allow | Out-Null
if($?){Write-Host 'Windows Firewall configured to allow incoming connections on TCP port 1433'}
```

You can dial this into your scenario, but you get the idea of what I'm doing.